How to Connect SQL Server on Azure VM to Power Apps (Canvas App) Without Public IP
I have an existing SQL Server hosted on an Azure Virtual Machine (VM) that’s part of a software system. My requirements are as follows:

The Azure VM does not have a public IP assigned to it.
I'm currently accessing the Azure VM through an on-premises data gateway.
I need to securely connect this SQL Server instance to a Power Apps Canvas app.


Are you getting any error?

With private IP on VM it's not possible to connect from Power Apps, both are on Microsoft owned networks but separate networks definitely.
Only way around to access SQL DB in Azure VM from Power Apps is to install and configure On-premises gateway on the machine. So, the VM on Azure is on-premise for Power Apps.
